# Visual Studio 2010 Web Deploy Error: Not allowed to begin a design-time build at this time for publish

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET MVC 3 app but I am getting

```
------ Publish started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Not allowed to begin a design-time build at this time for publish. Please try again later.

========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've published before successfully ... I even tried restarting Visual Studio and then the whole PC!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Errm, that error message returns zero results on google. What the heck have you invented? :)

Comment: If it was on google, I would've have posted the question, wouldn't I?
 ;)

Comment: 2 days passed since I posted this. I published successfully. Now I just want to understand why on earth this error occur cause last thing I want is to be awake all night for a delivery and this pops out

Comment: Hehe, of c you wouldnt :). Its just very rare that you find *nothing* about an error on google...

Comment: I just hit this error as well. Restarting VS got things back to normal. I was simply deploying to a local directory too so it isn't a connection issue. As to what causes this, I have no clue.

Comment: Getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this fails, quite honestly, but I restarted VS 2010 like @Keven Coulombe suggested and after that the publish went through. My guess is this might happen after debugging other projects, and having VS open for extended periods (For me this was about one week).